# How can I force an exception if the decimal is larger than the ToString format descriptor?

Tags: c#, format, decimal

I have to format decimals using various format descriptors passed to my code, which specify varying # of significant digits left of the decimal point. The ToString output cannot have too many digits on the left side per the format descriptor or I should return an error (format overflow).

Is there some ToString decimal format descriptor (I could not find any) or other decimal to string conversion mechanism where I can get an exception if the decimal is larger than the allocated string space for the left side of the decimal? I would like something like the below code to throw rather than work. I'm hoping for something more elegant/built in than my counting characters in the format descriptor and figuring out what is the maximum decimal for that myself and doing a compare before attempting the conversion. Thanks!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lFormat = null;
        decimal lValue = 123456.5678m;

        // For example, I would like something like this to throw because the number would not fit into 3 significant left side digits...
        lFormat = "000.00";
        Console.WriteLine("Format '{0}' value '{1}'.", lFormat, lValue.ToString(lFormat));

        Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You may be overthinking it: if (lValue > 999.999m) throw ...

Comment: Other than the format is not always ###.### and could have 2 or 3 or 4 or whatever significant left digits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any methods that have this behavior, however, you can implement your own quite easily. The body would look something like this;

```
int significantDigits = 4;


if (MyFloat.ToString().Split('.')[1].Length > significantDigits)
    throw new Exception("That float was too high of percision.");
```

You'll probably want to refine this code (it would crash with an IndexOutOfRangeException if they entered and int instead of float for example) but the basic idea is convert to string, split on `.`, check the length of index 1, throw an exception if it's greater than my limit.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I could do something like that but was hoping it could be part of the conversion process itself using the format descriptor mask rather than comparing the significant left side digits after the fact. But will go with this if no better built-in solution.

Comment: @Dave yeah it would be nice if you could refer to the fractional component on it's own but I don't think it's really an option with floats.

Comment: My ideal choice would be to have a FormatProvider mask where MyDecimalVaue.ToString("999.99") would overflow if the decimal value was 1000 or even 999.999 so would not fit in the mask.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to do this:

// check the decimal will not overflow the given format

decimal lMaxValue = decimal.Parse(new string('9', LeftPlaces) + "." + new string('9', RightPlaces));

if (pValue > lMaxValue)
   throw new OverflowException();